# Example of using mvp4g + gin on gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I made a long search but failed to find good example of using libraries like: mvp4g + gin on gwt. 

Can anyone share some links with an example ? 

Or post your little project where you training with these libraries ?

Comment: You can get it from the below link https://github.com/mvp4g/mvp4g-examples

Comment: which one of these examples using mvp4g + gin ?

Comment: Dependency Injection is done similar way as we do it with GWTP. Could you please elaborate more on your requirement ?

Comment: Side note: you should not start a project with GIN these days. Use Dagger 2 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already seen this tutorial?

https://github.com/mvp4g/mvp4g/wiki/08.-GIN-Integration

Answer (score 0):

Following are few reference sites. 
http://mvp4g.blogspot.nl/2011/04/mvp-pattern-associated-with-event-bus.html 
https://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/gwt-and-mvp4g-tutorial-1/

Comment: first one seems good, but second one i already saw(autor did only first part)